# strcat generates 1x1 cell in matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider the following snippet:

```
f=strcat(s,emotions{emotion},int2str(i),'\mean.points');
f1=strcat(s1,speakers(speaker),emotions{emotion},int2str(i),'\mean.points');
```

Here `emotions` and `speakers` are `1x7` and `1x4` arrays. The rest are strings and integers.

The type of `f1` comes out to be `1x1` cell while `f` remains a string. What could be the difference between the two?

Since it comes out to be a 1x1 cell I can't use it for `fopen()` without using an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If any input is a cell array, combinedStr is a cell array of strings. Otherwise, combinedStr is a character array.

In `f` you concatenate just char-arrays, but in `f1` obviously appears a cell array `speakers(speaker)`.

So just use `speakers{speaker}` also, and it should work.

With `()` you are indexing the cell array, therefore you get a cell element. With `{}` you are addressing the content of the specified cell.

Comment: So what is the difference between the `{}` and the `()` brackets while accessing an element?

Comment: With `()` you are indexing the cell array, therefore you get a cell element. With `{}` you are addressing the content of the specified cell.

Comment: It's like the question "Who sits in the red car?" - 1) Chose the red car! -> `car(red)` -> 2) Who sits inside? -> `car{red}`

Comment: @SohaibI - Type `help paren` or check out [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/specialcharacters.html).  There is some pretty esoteric but interesting functionality there.  For example, block commenting with `%{ %}` is unknown by most MATLAB users.

Comment: @SohaibI [it's available since R14](http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-17Y20/?solution=1-17Y20) - are you formatting it right?

Comment: @thewaywewalk I suppose so. formatting it right means? I just put `%{` before the block and `}%` after the block right?

Comment: @SohaibI End with `%}` instead.

Comment: @chappjc Arre typo! :P

Comment: @chappjc Im trying it across multiple lines. Thats how its supposed to work right?

Comment: @chappjc Okay got it! I wasnt putting it before the block in a separate line. Apparently if we put it in the same line as that of a statement it ends up not being a block comment.